# Search in MongoDB with Graphql (Foreign Key)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, search, graphql

Good afternoon.

I have 2 collections in mongoDB with a one-to-many relationship, where one of the collections receives the foreign key of the other.

```
const Sport = mongoose.model('Sport', new Schema({
_id: {
type: String,
default:() => uuid()
},
name: { type: String, required: true }
}))

const Event = mongoose.model('Event', new Schema({
_id: {
type: String,
default:() => uuid()
},
name: { type: String, required: true },
sport_id: { type: String, required: true }
}))
```

I want to do searches on these collections with graphql and when searching for Event, show the data from 'sport_id' instead of just showing the String. How do I do? How do I make the rootvalue?

```
type Sport {
        _id: String
        name: String
    }

type Event {
        _id: String
        name: String
        sport_id: Sport
    }

type Query {
        sport(name: String): [Sport!]
        sportById(_id: String): Sport

        event(name: String, sport_id: String): Event!
        eventById(_id: String): Event
    }
```